Building a line with D2D1
I have a couple of points, who are the input for linear regression. LR outputs the parameters w and b, so that the ideal line is
y = wx+b.
I would like to depict that line in D2D1 with the following command:
pRenderTarget->DrawLine(D2D1::Point2F(startX, startY), D2D1::Point2F(endX, endY), pBrush);
The problem is that i cannot figure out what the points startX, startY, endX, endY have to be. I tried with
startX = minX, startY = w * startX + b, endX = maxX, endY = w * endX + b 
where minX and minY are the minimum X and Y values in the dataset, but it gives a horizontal slope.


I tried to do something like this with R2D2 once but I couldn't understand the beep codes.
